# Removing the keying

Tags: keyframes

i made a new Blender Installation. Now I try to insert keyframes. This error message appears when I press "I": Keying set failed to insert any keyframes.
Another person had the same question here and answerd: remove the keying at the bottom. I cant find this window. Can someone help?

Comment: take a look at the Dope Sheet, make sure that you've unlocked the channels?

Comment: They might have meant the auto keying in the time line. https://i.imgur.com/PIOpHiv.png